# How to extract a decimal value from file using shell script in Ubuntu?

Tags: shell, gcc

The purpose of my code is

- To read two values from two separate files. [Working perfectly well]
- To convert them into decimal values. [Working fine]
- Find their differences. [Working fine]
- To make the difference positive if it is a negative  value. [**Not Working**, it's not checking the condition.]

Here is my code. Its coded in Ubuntu 11.04.

```
...
while read line;
do
echo -e "$line";
AllOn=$line
done<Output.log

gcc -Wall -o0 Test.c -o output
time -f "%e" -o BaseFile.log ./output
while read line;
do
echo -e "$line";
AllOff=$line
done<BaseFile.log

#Threshold Value
Threshold=`echo "$AllOff - $AllOn" | bc`;
echo "Threshold is $Threshold"
if [ `echo "$Threshold < 0.00"|bc` ]; then
   Threshold=`echo "$Threshold * -1" | bc`;
fi
echo "\nThreshold is $Threshold" >> $Result
```

Now, irrespective of the value, the `if clause` is getting executed. I think, my if condition is not being checked and that it would be the reason for the following output.

```
Base Time is 2.94
All Techniques Off = 3.09
Threshold is .15


Base Time is 3.07
All Techniques Off = 2.96
Threshold is -.11
```

**UPDATE:** This question is not answered completely yet and if any one could suggest me a way to achive my 4th objective of ***finding the difference*** between the values, it would be really helpful for me. Thank you.

Comment: If your input files do no tcontain the values as a lone number on the last line, your example code is incorrect. If the values need to be extracted from a line of text, we need to see an example. Awk should trivially handle that if the value is at a fixed position (say, the third space-separated word on a line would be `$3` in Awk).

Comment: My input files has got just those values in them. One file has the value `2.94` and the other file has the  value `3.09`. Now the only problem that I face is that my `if condition` is not being checked.

Comment: @tripleee- I had suggested 4 objectives at first and major 3 are solved. Now only last one objective is left. You can check my  edit history, if you doubt that.

Comment: @tripleee - I don't see anything that is not related to programming here. I had not accepted your answer just because it was beyond my level of understanding and I could use Phil's answer for my purpose if that bug with `if clause` was rectified.

Comment: @praveen - Tripleee's answer is preferable when you consider our solutions side by side. The solution Triplee provides is producing the absolute value if you're referring to the 4th objective being to 'To make the difference positive if it is a negative value', where you see 'if (sum < 0) sum *= -1;' in Tripleee's solution is where he is making certain the result is the absolute value of Threshold. My solution may be easier to grok for you, however, I really like Tripleee's solution for it's brevity and elegance - it's well worth learning what awk can achieve (I even learned a thing or two).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What shell are you using? I'm assuming just plain old 'sh' or 'bash'.

If so, look at line 33 where you have:

> if($Threshhold<0) then

Switch that to:

> if [ $Threshhold -lt 0 ]; then

You might have other issues, I haven't looked through the code closely to check for them.

To further expand, I knocked up test script and data (please note I changed 'Threshhold' to 'Threshold'):

```
# Example test.sh file
!/bin/bash

while read line;
do
echo "$line";
AllOn=$line
done < Output.log

while read line;
do
echo "$line";
AllOff=$line
done < BaseFile.log

#Threshhold Value
Threshold=`echo "$AllOn - $AllOff" | bc`;
echo "Threshold is $Threshold"
if [ `echo "$Threshold < 0"|bc` ]; then
  # snips off the '-' sign which is what you were trying to do it looks
  Threshold=${Threshold:1}
fi
echo $Threshold
Result=result.txt
echo "\nThreshold is $Threshold" >> $Result
```

Then some data files, first Output.log:

```
# Output.log
1.2
```

Then BaseFile.log:

```
# BaseFile.log
1.3
```

Example output from the above:

```
./test.sh
1.2
1.3
Threshold is -.1
.1
```

Comment: Before that I want it converted from string to decimal in order to perform this check.

Comment: I've made an edit to Tripleee's post demonstrating use of his solution, which I recommend using, it's waiting on peer review to be approved. As Tripleee says though, his solution can replace whatever shell script you're trying to create (if it's just there to do the addition). The solution I've added shows how to embed his solution into your script if it does more work.

Answer (score 1):

Bourne shell has no built-in facility for arithmetic. The assignment

```
Threshhold=$AllOn-$AllOff
```

simply concatenates the two strings with a minus sign between them.

In Bash, you can use

```
Threshhold=$(($AllOn-$AllOff))
```

but that will still not allow the comparison to zero. For portability, I would simply use Awk for the entire task.

```
#!/bin/sh
gcc -Wall -o0 Test.c -o output
time -f "%e" -o BaseFile.log ./output
awk 'NR==FNR { allon=$0; next }
    { alloff=$0 }
    END { sum=allon-alloff; 
        if (sum < 0) sum *= -1; 
        print "Threshold is", sum }' Output.log BaseFile.log >>$Result
```

Comment: I personally prefer this answer for brevity

Comment: I don't understand how I could do this with my code. Could you please explain this with my code so that all my requirements are fulfilled?

Comment: Tripleee pretty much has given you everything you need apart from writing the script file for you.

Comment: This already handles the absolute value. So does the other answer. There are alternate solutions in comments. Your problem is elsewhere.